# windows 8.1 top app bar

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

[image: Top App bar]

I saw many windows store apps using this top app bar. I thought that there is a sample for it but i didn't find any.
But there is a similar sample for it using HTML only rather than XAML [HTML NavBar control sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HTML-NavBar-control-sample-4472d92a)
so could anybody tell me whether i can find an implementation for it in xaml or even for the one in the HTML sample. if there isn't could any body lead me on the way for implementing it as i tried to implement it but i went into many problems.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could get you started

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <Button Style="{StaticResource AStyle}" Click="Home_Button_Click" HorizontalAlignement =Center/>
     <Button Style="{StaticResource AStyle}" Click="Home_Button_Click" HorizontalAlignement =Center/>
       </StackPanel>
   </AppBar>

</Page.TopAppBar>
```

**EDITS**
I have completed my research and you can add a sub menu at the end by doing the following :

```
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="By rating" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" Tag="rating"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="By match" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" Tag="match"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="By distance" Click="MenuFlyoutItem_Click" Tag="distance"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
```

More than this, this following link explains all about creating a sub-menu on WPF. I know that you're working on WP8.1, but XAML remains XAML and you should get a pretty nice idea from the code you're about to see there.

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument6878

Comment: do you  have any idea  how to implement the sub menu at the bottom ?

Comment: Please, look at my answer, I have added some new content

Comment: @Assem-Hafez it's has been a LONG time ago, but if that answer helped you in the past, accept it so when users come accros this, they'll know this is probably the way to go

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the appbar in you XAML file, like this:

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
<AppBar>
    <!-- AppBar content -->
</AppBar>
```

replace the appbar content with AppBarButtons or whatever content you like, you can even add custom XAML code(Grids, stackpanels ...)

Comment: i already done that but i the main problem was implementing the sub menu. i used flyout but i went into problems of positioning it. but it seems that they didn't use  flyouts as in my case the top app bar disappears after to taps on the screen (one for the flyout and one for the app bar) while in their case it disappears after one tap